# prestashop display attachment inline

Tags: php, prestashop, tcpdf

I'm creating a custom PDF file containing some product details. I would like to display product attachments that are images. I have changed the attachment controller to

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.utf8_decode($a->file_name).'"');
```

When I visit the url through the browser it displays nicely:

```
http://domain.nl/nl/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=483
```

But using this url inside an img tag in my PDF template gives:

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: http://domain.nl/nl/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=483
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Do you have a line like `header('Content-type: application/pdf')`?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new file next to AttachmentController.php called AttachmentInlineController.php. Contents are slightly different:

```
<?php
class AttachmentInlineControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $a = new Attachment(Tools::getValue('id_attachment'), $this->context->language->id);
        if (!$a->id) {
            Tools::redirect('index.php');
        }


        if (ob_get_level() && ob_get_length() > 0) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Type: '.$a->mime);
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize(_PS_DOWNLOAD_DIR_.$a->file));
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.utf8_decode($a->file_name).'"');
        @set_time_limit(0);
        readfile(_PS_DOWNLOAD_DIR_.$a->file);
        exit;

    }
}?>
```

I removed the hook, changed content-Disposition to inline, and changed the function from `postProcess()` to `__construct`. Now if you use:

`http://domain.nl/nl/index.php?controller=attachmentInline&id_attachment=483`

It will display that attachment inline, and you can use this url in image tags etc.